# A server goes down affecting many developers, is the question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

The specific case is an Apple's Geocoder server, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819466/error-return-address-clgeocoder. It seemed quite busy for the duration of the bug, many upvotes, answers <sup>(4 deleted)</sup> and about half a thousand views. Is the question on-topic because it's an historic signpost that something like this can occur during development? Or is it off-topic because it's not a problem with `code`?

The OP [cross-posted the same Geocoder question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16857/erro-ao-retornar-endereco-do-clgeocorder) at Stack Overflow em Português and we're having [a meta discussion](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1401/a-pergunta-erro-ao-retornar-endereco-do-clgeocorder-e-descontextualizada/1406?noredirect=1#comment3779_1406) if it's on-topic there. But to make this a *true cross-post*, I'm opening this question here to know how does our *big brother* deals with something like this.

My first reaction was "this is unrelated to programming", but now I'm less convinced that this is not a programming related problem...

Comment: 100.00000000% of questions about programming, **become spectacularly redundant.**  And they do so really quickly.  SO is pretty much the most redundant site on the internet.  Every single word on SO becomes totally redundant in as little as one year, 2-3 at the most. If SO has a policy "nothing topical!! we're too neat for that!!!!!" - that's fine and it's SO's choice to do that: but it's worth noting that it's an incredibly ... ironic ... position for programmers to take.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was on-topic during its time (although an observant reader might notice that the errors mention a 500 status code coming from an Apple server), but should now be closed as no longer reproducible since it was indeed a temporary problem.

I don't think this question, or indeed any particular question of its kind, needs to remain as a signpost. Should a similar problem crop up again in the future, a new question can be posted. The community can then determine if that new problem is external as well, or really a problem with the code that is given instead.

Comment: Well, looks like the observant reader just answered both questions, the original and the meta.

Answer (score 2):

The question is clearly off-topic. It's not a programming issue, at least, not ours; it's transient (it's not a problem now) and as in this case, it may not even be reproducible at the time.

There are plenty of other resources on the web that can help verify whether a site is up or down so there's no need to clutter Stack Overflow with the noise.

Lastly, the problem with leaving this question on the site is that later visitors will see it and assume that it's OK to post something similar, which it isn't.

I see that [Boltclock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) has already closed the question. I'm a little surprised that he didn't just delete it. I've bookmarked it so that I can vote to delete it in a day or so.

Comment: How long before delete votes can be cast?

Comment: @brasofilo for 10k+ users it's two days, but I'm not sure when the clock starts on that. 20k users can delete questions more quickly under some circumstances.