# Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: discussion, portuguese-stack-overflow

I saw there is a Portuguese version of Stack Overflow.

- Why is there a Portuguese version of Stack Overflow? Since we have two versions (English and Portuguese), programming questions are decentralized. (For example, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256332/a-server-goes-down-affecting-many-developers-is-the-question-on-topic) has been asked twice.)
- Is there any relation between these two sites? (I can imagine shared reputation for example.)
- Do they handle questions with a duplicate on Stack Overflow?

*(PS: I do not know whether this question belong to meta.stackoverflow.)*

Comment: See [Can’t We All be Reasonable and Speak English?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/) And they are two distinct sites. Different accounts. Different rep. No cross-site duplicates.

Comment: See also: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).

Comment: And another somwhat related MSE discussion [Is it OK to crosspost Stack Overflow questions, now that the Portuguese SO is open?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218055/is-it-ok-to-crosspost-stack-overflow-questions-now-that-the-portuguese-so-is-op)

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is a Portuguese version of SO...because some people speak Portuguese.

The main Stack Overflow is in English, though we do sometimes get code in a different language, which is usually not a problem because the basic principles are the same.

There is even an [official policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) that requires posts to be in English.

One of the largest problems with low-quality answers is simply the language barrier: people who don't speak English have to use a translator for their post and then translate the answers and comments when they come in. Obviously, this isn't conducive to well thought-out and formatted posts because the language has to be kept as simple as possible and the grammar can sometimes get iffy with online translators.

Going through a translator often muddies the water even further because it creates an understanding issue between posters.

How do we solve this?

With a site for people who speak other languages, of course.

Stack Overflow in Portuguese is currently the only official foreign language Stack Overflow, but there are a few (more than a few) proposals in [Area 51](//area51.stackexchange.com) following its lead (see [Korean](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68765/stack-overflow-in-korean), [Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), [German](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german), [Persian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58858/stack-overflow-in-persian), [Arabic](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58628/stack-overflow-in-arabic), [Polish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56923/stack-overflow-in-polish), [Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) (close to public beta), and [Russian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) (close to public beta)).

Having separate language sites reduces friction between posters and allows people to speak with people of their own language to solve problems more efficiently (barring [some issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256753/c-is-irritating-english-too-no)).

Reputation is not shared between them because they are different sites, and "duplicates" are not duplicates because the question, its answer(s), and the attached discussion are in a different language.